# Add scriptmethod member

Tags: powershell

this is an example from "the" book "Windows PowerShell in Action 3-edition", Bruce Payette, adding scriptmethod to an existing object and reverse itself, I've tried with PS 5 and PS 7:

```
$s = "hi world"
$sb = {
$a = [char[]] $this
[array]::reverse($a)
-join $a
}
$s | add-member -MemberType ScriptMethod -name Reverse -value $sb
```

There is no error message, but no method "Reverse" will be created as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: **[Example 3: Add a StringUse note property to a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member#example-3-add-a-stringuse-note-property-to-a-string)**

> Because `Add-Member` can't add types to String input objects, you can specify the [`PassThru`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.3#-passthru) parameter to generate an output object.

```
$sb = {
    $a = [char[]] $this
    [array]::reverse($a)
    -join $a
}

$s = "hi world"
$s = $s | add-member -MemberType ScriptMethod -name Reverse -value $sb  -PassThru
$s.reverse()
dlrow ih
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Strangely enough, that the book's authors don't mention it in this example...